# Yii2 - How can I remove unnecessary information from log file?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I am trying to log messages in Yii2 which are then emailed to my specified email address.

config file `web.php` contains:

```
'mail' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\EmailTarget',
                    'categories' => ['mail'],
                    'logVars' => [],
                    'mailer' => 'mailer',
                    'message' => [
                        'from' => ['user@example.com'],
                        'to' => ['user1@example.com'],
                        'subject' => 'Log message',
                    ],
                ],
```

I am logging message like this:

```
Yii::info('Log message example','mail');
```

After successful execution, I am receiving mail like this:

```
2018-07-31 09:01:12 [127.0.0.1][user@example.com][-][info][mail] Log message example
```

So what I am trying to do is that I want to remove unwanted information like IP address, User Name etc. from this messages and at the end what I want is

```
2018-07-31 09:01:12 Log message example
```

Comment: Extend the `yii\log\EmailTarget` class and go bananas with the log message?

Comment: So Yii internally does not provide functionality to manage customized log messages.?

Comment: Have you tried configuring the [prefix](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-logging#message-formatting)? Still the easiest way would to be create your own log handler.

Comment: No, I haven't tried it yet. But I got it what you are trying to say. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove first three parts from log by setting [`prefix`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-log-target#$prefix-detail) property:

```
'mail' => [
    'class' => 'yii\log\EmailTarget',
    'categories' => ['mail'],
    'logVars' => [],
    'prefix' => function () {
        return '';
    },
    'mailer' => 'mailer',
    'message' => [
        'from' => ['user@example.com'],
        'to' => ['user1@example.com'],
        'subject' => 'Log message',
    ],
],
```

Last two parts (level and category) are hardcoded, you need to extend `EmailTarget` and override [`formatMessage()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-log-target#formatMessage()-detail) to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

You can set this either in your configuration file `web.php` or in your code.

```
Yii::$app->log->targets['test']->prefix = function (){
        return null;
};
```

or

```
'mail' => [
       'class' => 'yii\log\EmailTarget',
       'categories' => ['mail'],
       'logVars' => [],
       'mailer' => 'mailer',
       'prefix' => function () {
           return null;
       },
       'message' => [
       'from' => ['user@example.com'],
       'to' => ['user1@example.com'],
       'subject' => 'Log message',
     ],
],
```